# CSS selector hierarchy? How to reverse engineer to get the styling?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
.post .post_author div.author_avatar img {

}
```

edited: to be clear, I have a given CSS ruleset, that I would like to apply to my html, and i would like to know how to set up the html to apply the ruleset when the rules specify a collection of classes.

how do i reproduce that selector in html from the CSS?

```
<div class="post post_author author_avatar"><img /></div>
```

doesnt that give me the css styling?

Comment: "doesnt that give me the css styling?" Why would it? Your class selectors are completely separated and the `div` type selector is only attached to the last one.

Comment: Looks like you need

<div class="post"><div class="post_author"><div class="author_avatar"><img />

Comment: I'm confused now. Are you trying to get the HTML based on a CSS selector? Is that what you mean by "reverse engineer"?

Comment: Please describe the problem concretely, without using abstract terms like “selector hierarchy” (something undefined) or “reverse engineer” (very vague and general). Reproducing a selectors “from the CSS” is a meaningless concept. We can probably guess what you really mean, but the question and answers to it won’t be useful to future visitors if there is no understandable problem description.

Comment: its as best as i can describe it :P i have a CSS class in a hierarchy and i needed to apply that class in that hierachy.....and since I am a noob, i thought i would call them all in one parent element, but you need separate "hierarchy" elements

Comment: Well, it's not going to work - you're going to have to change either your CSS or your HTML to match the other. What's unclear is which one you're trying to do.

Comment: There are no CSS classes. Classes have no hierarchy in HTML. You have not told us what the goal is and what you actually have. What you *probably* mean is that you have a fixed CSS rule somewhere for some reason and you need to construct HTML markup that creates an element that matches the rule. If this is so, you should edit the question to describe it.

Comment: I cannot change the css class ruleset, which i think is applied or called from the parent element, and then down to the final element. SO i have to "reverve engineer" the ruleset, starting with the IMG, then the DIV.author_avatar, and so on. what i do not understand is if I dont need the extra elements, that i can call all the other classes into ONE element or not

Comment: Why can you not change the CSS? That makes little sense. Trying to write HTML so that it matches a “given CSS” is very unusual, and will end up with HTML code that probably won’t make much sense.

Comment: when you are trying to integrate into phpBB or any forum packages, what makes less sense is to create more bloated CSS when you have the css classes already designed for you....as an example twitter bootstrap is a predefined CSS (plus JS) you dont need to (re) write when you can re-use ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector represents

> an `img` element
>   that is a descendant of a `div` element with the `.author_avatar` class
>   that is a descendant of an element with the `.post_author` class
>   that is a descendant of an element with the `.post` class.

Each of these classes is represented by a separate element. The space between each selector is a descendant combinator. So you will need to create up to three `div`s (or other elements depending on your layout, but `.author_avatar` must be a `div`):

```
<div class="post">
  <div class="post_author">
    <div class="author_avatar">
      <img />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.post.post_author.author_avatar img`.

Comment: This answer would be much better if it had an explanation as to why it would work as opposed to what the OP already has. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: would that allow me to use all the classes in one parent div element?

Although i cannot change the CSS in this project but would like to know

Comment: @Chaz Le: Yes, it would.

Comment: so what would the html be?

[code]<div class="post.post_author.author_avatar"><img /></div>[/code]

Comment: or can i just call any of the classes?

Comment: @ChazLe No, the above CSS selector works only if you write the HTML in your question.